# How to make a object in flast move to it's rotating angle?

Tags: flash, rotation

I want to make for example a sqare which rotates when i press lefr or right arrow key and when i press up arrow key i want it to go to the direction it's facing. I don't know if it's possible with actionscript 2...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In AS2 you can apply a vector returning a new xy based on a speed

```
function setVector(dir:Number, speed:Number):Array
{
    var xspeed:Number = Math.cos(dir*Math.PI/180)*speed;
    var yspeed:Number = Math.sin(dir*Math.PI/180)*speed;
    var retArray:Array = new Array(xspeed, yspeed);
    return retArray;
}
```

you will need to calculate the frame time to give an accurate movement

```
var frameStartTime:Number = getTimer();
var frameTime:Number = getTimer();
var direction:Number = 10;
var speed:Number = 50;
var coords:Object = new Object();

this.onEnterFrame = function():Void
{
    frameTime = frameStartTime - getTimer();
    frameStartTime = getTimer();
    tileVector = setVector(direction, (Number * frameTime));
    coords.x = Number(coords.x) + Number(tileVector[0]);
    coords.y = Number(coords.y) + Number(tileVector[1]);
    tileMC._x = coords.x;
    tileMC._y = coords.y;
}
```

I have not tested this code fully but it should... Point you in the right direction... Please ignore the pun.